# Struts 2 : Return XML Result

Tags: xml, struts2

I nedd to return an XML file in struts Action results, and I search over the web but I didn't find something about it .

I have some statics data that I need to return as an XML file to and these data will be processed using AJAX .

Can any body help me ?

Comment: you need to Elaborate a little on the problem or post the code for your Action. Do you want to know how to convert Java Object into XML or do you already have an XML that you just want to return?

Comment: I have some statics data that I need to return as an XML file to and these data will be processed using AJAX .

Comment: How would it be processed? Show the code what did you try.

Answer (score 0):

#### 1 Scenario 1: Already have a XML that you want to return:

Just set

```
response.setContentType("application/xml");
return yourXML;
```

#### 2.Scenario 2: You want to convert java object to xml

You can use something like JAXB or XStream to generate XML from your Java Objects. and then use Scenario 1. Here's a tutorial link for each :

XStream: [http://x-stream.github.io//tutorial.html](http://x-stream.github.io/tutorial.html)

JAXB: http://www.mkyong.com/java/jaxb-hello-world-example/

Answer (score 0):

You need to create an XML (either with XStream, JAXB or similar tools), then assign it to an InputStream and return a result mapped to a [Stream Result](http://struts.apache.org/release/2.3.x/docs/stream-result.html) , specifying the appropriate contentType (`application/xml`) and the desired filename / contentDisposition.

Answer (score 0):

In your struts.xml

```
<action name="getXml" method="getMyXml" class="myActionClass">
  <result name="xml" type="stream">
    <param name="contentType">application/xml</param>
    <param name="inputName">xmlInputStream</param>
  </result>
</action>
```

in your action class

```
class myActionClass{
  InputStream xmlInputStream;
  XmlClass xmlClass;
  public InputStream getXmlInputStream() {
    return this.xmlInputStream;
  }

  public String getMyXml() {
    this.inputStream = new ByteArrayInputStream(
        "<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?><foo><bar>foobar</bar></foo>"
         .getBytes("UTF-8"));
    return "xml";
  }
}
```